# Why does f major scale have a flat instead of a sharp?

Tags: diatonic

I was practicing my scales on the piano and I started to wonder why the F major scale is written with a Bflat rather then an A#?

Comment: the convention is to use different note names for each scale degree so f,g,a,bflat,c,d,e.. if you would've used a# it would look like f,g,a,a#,c,d,e ... but now you have two a's. and that's not cool with the convention.

Comment: @foreyez -- quite true; also, with A♯ there would be an augmented unison between the 3rd and 4th degrees of the F major scale, which isn't at all how we think of major scales. With B♭ instead there is instead a minor second between the 3rd and 4th degrees, and we can all breathe a little easier.... ;)